# How to access custom Zend Form Element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I created a Phone.php file in inside application/forms/elements directory.  The class signature is as follows:
`class Form_Element_Phone 
        extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml`

In my Bootstrap I have the following:

```
$autoLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader( array(
                                            'namespace' => '',
                                            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ) );

            return $autoLoader;
```

I thought this would autoload the custom form element when I type `$phone = new Form_Element_Phone( 'phone' );`  in my form object in application/forms directory.
Why did this not work? Shouldn't everything under the application directory be accessible in this manner because of the code in the Bootstrap file???  I am getting `Fatal error: Class 'Form_Element_Phone' not found` error.

I also tried `$this->addElementPrefixPath('Form_Element', APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/elements');`  in the init function of my form class. But it did not change anything.  What am I doing wrong?  I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Men

```
 public function _initAutoload()
    {    

        $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                 'basePath'  =>APPLICATION_PATH,
                 'namespace' => '',
                 'resourceTypes' => array(
                      'form'  => array(
                           'path'      => 'forms/',
                           'namespace' => 'Form_',  
                         ),
                        'model' => array(
                              'path' => 'models/',
                              'namespace' => 'Model_'
                         ),

                         'validator' =>array(
                             'path'       => 'validators/',
                             'namespace'  => 'Validator_'  
                         ), 
                         'plugin' => array(
                              'path' => 'plugins/',
                              'namespace' => 'Plugin_'
                         ),
                         'helper' => array(
                              'path' => 'helpers/',
                              'namespace' => 'Helper_'
                        ),
                      ),
                 ));

      $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                     'namespace' => '',
                     'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default' ));
      return $modelLoader;
      return $resourceLoader;
       }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  What are "resourceTypes"? What are rules for declaring them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you form inside.  Maybe you did mistake when call it.
Like:

class Form_SomeForm extends Zend_Form

Check it 
And Check in Controller when you ask for the form

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your autoloader in your global config file with just a namespace, you should be able to avoid any complicated custom code to set this up.  In my `application.ini`, I have the following:

```
appnamespace = "Application"
```

ZF's resource loader has a default location for forms in `APPLICATION_PATH/forms`.  So with the above, my form class names start with `Application_`.  To use a custom form element, you could create `APPLICATION_PATH/forms/Element/Phone.php`, and use the class name `Application_Form_Element_Phone`.  I tried this just now and it works great.  If the `Application` prefix on your class names is too long, you could replace it with something shorter, like `App` or `My`.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Can you please explain to me what I did wrong?  I already had appspace defined the way you suggest.  But it is my understanding that I don't need to put "Application" infront of class names because of the code in my Bootstrap file.  Am I wrong?  I built all my controllers and forms without putting "Application" in their class names.  Also, doesn't Zend naming convention ask that I name the directory "elements" instead of "Element"?  It should turn 'Element' into 'elements' when searching for classes.  Am I wrong about that as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong with your original setup.  I've never done it without some kind of appnamespace prefix.  I just tend to opt for using ZF's default configurations and conventions where feasible, since it means less code to write and debug.  But yeah, it could mean some refactoring to switch to this now.  As for the Element directory, I think it would need to be lower-cased only if it's listed in your Resource loader config.  In my solution, it's a subfolder not directly listed.  APPLICATION_PATH/forms/Element worked in my own testing.  I didn't try APPLICATION_PATH/forms/elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will have to register the empty namespace with the Autoloader. To do this, you will have to use `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`. You should add this to the application `Bootstrap`. Note: most of this was already mentioned by @user854029, but forgot the `Form_Element_` namespace.

```
protected _initAutoload()
{
    // the __construct of this class registers this resource with Zend_Loader_Autoloader
    new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        // This base path prepends paths defined in the resourceTypes below
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => '',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'form' => array(
                'path' => 'forms/',
                'namespace' => 'Form_'
            ),
            // the key 'element' is an arbitrary name I used, it's not special
            'element' => array(
                // Now we set the path we need to append to basePath set above                
                'path' => 'forms/elements',
                // And now we have to declare the namespace
                'namespace' => 'Form_Element_'
            ),
            'model' => array(
                'path' => 'models/',
                'namespace' => 'Model_'
            )
            /** You can add the rest here as need **/
        )
    ));
    // Note: you don't have to return anything

}
```

On a further note, consider moving custom class to your Application's `library` directory.

**EDIT**

```
protected _initAutoload()
{
    //Removed Autoloader_Resoure and Replaced with Module_Autoloader
     new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => '',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'element' => array(  
                'path'      => 'forms/elements', // This is custom
                'namespace' => 'Form_Element'
            )
        )
    ));

}
```

Comment: I can now access the custom form element.  But now I get following error:

Comment: Warning: Exception caught by form: Plugin by name 'PhoneElement' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/application/views/helpers/
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('PhoneElement')
#1 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'phoneElement')
#2 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/ViewHelper.php(241):

Comment: Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('phoneElement')
#3 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/Form/Element.php(2023): Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper->render('')
#4 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/FormElements.php(101): Zend_Form_Element->render()
#5 /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/Form.php(2908): Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements->render('')
#6 /home/ryy/Si in /home/ryy/Sites/public_html/tmpsolution.com/library/Zend/Form.php on line 2929

Comment: I am sorry about posting the error message this way.  Stackoverflow won't let me do it any other way.  The  view helper is in application/veiws/helpers/.  According to the 2nd line of error message ZF is looking for it there.  The class signature for it is "class View_Helper_PhoneElement
  extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement"

Comment: This is a new problem. It's saying that your Helper is not found. So, you will have to register the helper path and namespace with the view. `$view->addHelperPath('Path/To/Helper', 'Path_To_Helper');`

Comment: I also went ahead and added the following to the bootstrap:'view' => array(
        'path' => 'views/',
        'namespace' => 'View_'
      ),
      'helper' => array(
        'path' => 'views/helpers',
        'namespace' =>'View_Helper_'
      )

Comment: That won't work unless you instantiate the class directly using `new View_Helper_Element()`. In order for the helper to work, you have to register it with the view. `$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/', 'View_Helper_');`

Comment: Well, whether you like it or not you just acquired a new subscriber to your blog.  Your suggestion worked.  I still don't understand what you did with `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`.  I was told that I only need to define the basepath and everything else falls into place. Is that information incorrect?

Comment: Thanks. You could have used `new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
   'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
   'namespace' => ''
  ))` and it would save you from writing all the resoureTypes manually, but that still won't register the view helpers with the View AND it won't register the custom path to Elements. Ok, next blog post, I will explain in detail.

Comment: I look forward that post.  BTw, I am also interesting Java web development.  Could you guys please discuss how to install a Java/apache web server along with php/apache webserver?  That would be a tremendous help.